# Выравнивание текста в блоке по центру

Tags: css

Почему данный код не выравнивает текст по центру?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.block{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 20%;
  max-height: 50%;
  background: greenyellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.block h4 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
    <h4> 
        abacaba
    </h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А в каком месте вы его выравниваете? :)

Comment: @IgorTkachuk .block h4 {margin: auto}

Comment: `margin: auto` работает только тогда, когда задана ширина для элемента. В данном случаи ширина тега `h4` равна 100% от ширины родителя и `margin` не может его отцентровать!

Comment: @IgorTkachuk спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

`margin: auto;` - выравнивает блок за счёт добавление отступов по краям, но так-как ваш блок на всю ширину, то отступы не добавляются, им просто не где быть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видно что блок во всю ширину и отступов нету.
**Вариант 1**
Всё таки выравнивать блок `h1`, задать ему не полную ширину.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ширина 75px и видны отступы и блок по центру, но не текст.
**Вариант 2**
Выравнивать сам текст внутри `h1`: `text-align: center` - выравнивает текст в блоке `h1`, а не сам блок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Блок во всю ширину, но текст по центру.

Answer (score 1):

`margin: auto;` не работает потому что элемент `h4` занимает всю ширину блока `.block` и ей как-бы негде ставить отступ.
Если попробуйте задавать элементу `h4` например `width:60px;` то он выравнивается по центру блока `.block`.

Answer (score 0):

Напиши : `text-align:center;` в `.block`

Comment: Работает, но все же непонятно, почему margin: auto не работает

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что H4 это блочный элемент и он занимает всю ширину родительского документа.

Чем не устраивает простой:

```
h4 { text-align: center; }
```

Ну или если обязательно нужны margin'ы, то можно так:

```
h4 { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Можете посмотреть руководство по [выравниванию в CSS](https://tuhub.ru/posts/centering-css-complete-guide).